# Interpreting an OLS regression where treatment is spatially associated to confounder

Tags: least-squares, causality, spatial, treatment-effect, treatment

I am reading a study that is running an OLS regression to assess the effect of a treatment ($T$) on an outcome ($y$). Outcome $y$ is a disease, and the treatment group is strongly spatially associated with the spreading vector of the disease. The design of the "experiment" is best described with the picture below.

The regression run is the following. For each individual $i$,living in location $\ell$, they estimate $\hat{\beta}$ and $\hat{\lambda}$ in the following regression equation using OLS.

$$y_{i\ell} = \beta \mathbf{1}\text{\{T = 1\}}_i + \lambda \text{Distance to spread line}_{\ell} + \varepsilon_{i\ell}$$

I am very puzzled by this. Clearly, distance to the spread line is an important determinant of the disease. Controlling for it would give me the effect of the treatment,*ceteris paribus*. But what does *ceteris paribus* here mean given that the distances to the line don't have the same support in the treatment and control group? What assumptions on the effect of the variable "Distance to spread line" do we need for this to actually work? Is it just that the effect is linear?

And if the effect is non-linear, can they just get away by adding higher-order polynomial terms, given again the lack of common support?

This is beyond my math/stats skills, but my hunch is that this design can be a problem.

[image]